# Xampp version 1.7.7 php code doesn 't work

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have installed Xampp version 1.7.7 for windows and i want to start learning php. The problem here is I can 't run php code.

I tried this very simple example

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Ofcorse I don t double click the php file and I don t just execute it in Firefox.
I go to

```
 http://localhost/xampp/htdocs/helloworld.php
```

which is the correst direction, I have checked it several times.
I tried for index.php too but it doesn 't work too. I get this error.

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually
please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
05/21/12 15:17:22
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4   
Perl/v5.10.1
```

I have installed Xampp with default options and when i click on admin (xampp xontrol panel) I get the classic orange page. When I go on status menu it shows that everything is activated except SMTP service and Tomcat service. I have tried to uninstall and reinstall xampp and nothing changed.

I have also searched on the web but nothing seems to help. 
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
http://localhost/helloworld.php
```

if you save the file at xampp/htdocs/

Comment: Wow!!! I never thought it will be so easy!!! Thank you, and I am sorry that I can 't leave you a rep :( Sometimes easy things can t come in mind!!!

Answer (score 3):

try 
    http:// localhost/helloworld.php 
C:...\xampp\htdocs\ is your document root, so the server fetchs the file from this folder, and they can be accessed by firefox via http:// localhost/file.php

Comment: thank you !! it was easier than i thought! sorry for the silly question!